# Is there a way to retrieve the sessions allocated by rtpproxy?

Tags: sip, voip, rtp, opensips

I have an OpenSIPS proxy running with RTPProxy. The calls are working fine and the media is relayed to RTPProxy. Is there a way to figure out what are the allocations used by the server? Can I query RTPProxy for all available sessions and see the allocated ports?

What I tried so far is to intercept the communication between RTPProxy and OpenSIPS, and I have information about the allocations, but not about the UAC/UAS port numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

There's a UDP based interface that transfers Bencoded data, it's how OpenSIPs and Kamailio interface with RTPproxy - It's called the ng protocol.

[The full documentation is in the Readme on GitHub,](https://github.com/sipwise/rtpengine)

[I wrote an example Python client for rtpengine's *ng protocol* a while back.](https://nickvsnetworking.com/rtpengine-python-api-calls-via-ng-control-protocol/) It just lists the current calls so probably quite a good place to start if you're a Python fan.